# Send Image as a binary file to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c

The below is the attribute where I send my image to the server to get the information about the image.

```
    NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"en_US", @"image_request[locale]", @"en", @"image_request[language]",[NSURL URLWithString:@"<file url>"], @"image_request[image]", nil];
```

To upload the image am using the code below :

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
```

But the parameter is asking me to provide the url.Is there any way that as soon as I snap a photo and upload it to server and get that url and append that in the parameter or any alternative to be found.And am using Unirest http library to send the request.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You said the server requires you to upload an image as binary and then you said the server requires an image URL. Which is it?

Comment: If u go to this https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/camfind#!documentation the attribute requires NSURL but the endpoint description says Binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to transmit an image captured with the camera to CamFind API using Unirest, you need to same the image first.

```
// Get the path to the Documents folder
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Get the path to an file named "tmp_image.jpg" in the Documents folder
NSString *imagePath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp_image.jpg"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];

// Write the image to an file called "tmp_image.jpg" in the Documents folder
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[imageData writeToURL:imageURL atomically:YES];

// Now construct the parameters that will be passed to Unirest
NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"en_US", @"image_request[locale]", @"en", @"image_request[language]", imageURL, @"image_request[image]", nil];

// And the headers
NSDictionary* headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"<mashape-key>", @"X-Mashape-Authorization", nil];

// Call the API using Unirest
HttpJsonResponse* response = [[Unirest post:^(BodyRequest* request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests"];
    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];
```

Comment: I will try that.But I tried to use BodyRequest instead i have this HttpJsonResponse *response = [[Unirest postEntity:^(MultipartRequest* request)]]; what is the difference??

Comment: Where can i get more examples of Unirest library?

Comment: How to print json output using Unirest

Comment: JsonNode* json = [response body];     
    NSLog(@"Answer = %@",json);
Output- Answer = <JsonNode: 0x1c5fb070>.. How to get json output with curl braces..

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", json.isArray ? json.JSONArray : json.JSONObject);` Read the [header file](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-obj-c/blob/master/Unirest/HttpResponse/JsonNode.h) next time.

Comment: got token from json.JSONArray from that token I need to get name of the image HttpRequest *getResponse = [[Unirest get:^(SimpleRequest *request){
        [request setUrl:@"https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_responses/json.JSONObject"];
  [request setHeaders:getHeaders];
               [request setParameters:getParameters];

    }] asJson];  I am getting error -- no visible interface for setParameter.I even check the header file but no information regarding that 
https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-obj-c/blob/master/Unirest/HttpRequestWithBody.m and I also tried http://unirest.io/ but no use..

Comment: That should be a separate question, not a comment.

Comment: can you please help me on passing the token and getting the information.