# How to send image via unirest?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, unirest

There is some documentation in **Mashape/UNIREST** about file uploading.

But i don't understand why i have to use NSURL for this purposes.
Simply, i don't understand how to pass UIImage to request parameters.
This solution didn't help me, also

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
NSString *imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Finally, the question is:

How to upload UIImage to server via UNIREST?

Comment: Here's an example that shows you how. Uses unirest.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380980/send-image-as-a-binary-file-to-the-server

Answer (score -4):

I refused unirest, AFNetworking is better